Power Query - Get data from file where part of file name changes each time
I'm trying to use power Query to automatically bring in data to review. I have my excel template setup to bring in data from an Excel file. I have 18 files and they each go into their own tab in my 1 master spreadsheet. This is exactly what I need except I ran into an issue with the file names. Currently the file names are Query1, Query2, Query3 etc. but they can also be named Query1 Company1, Query1 Company 2. So the first part of the file name Query1, Query2 etc will always be the same but the Company name after will be different each time. Is there any way for power query to bring in a file based on the first part of the file name and ignore the rest of it?
I tried to bring in data from a folder instead of grabbing each file one by one, but it just brought in the file names into my spreadsheet. I've watched many YouTube videos to try and figure this out, but haven't had any luck yet.

You can restrict the files to be examined with a simple filter, but Power Query will nost be able to take the list, and output a processed table to multiple worksheets.

Thank you, that's what I was finding. I did find that Windows will let you highlight multiple files and rename them. So If I rename them Query, I'll get Query(1) Query(2) etc. Which I can make work!
